# Как получить список репозиториев пользователя GitHub через API?

Tags: ajax, github, запрос, fetch, github-api

Пробовал через [https://api.github.com/users/${name}](https://api.github.com/users/$%7Bname%7D), но он выдает только данные пользователя. Пробовал также [https://api.github.com/users/${name}/repos](https://api.github.com/users/$%7Bname%7D/repos) - это не дает ожидаемого результата.

Вот код того, что пробовал:

```
async function getUsers(namesAr) {
let jobs = [];

for(let name of namesAr) {
    let job = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}/repos`).then(
        successResponse => {
            if (successResponse.status != 200) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return successResponse.json();
            }
        },
        failResponse => {
            return null;
        }
    );
    jobs.push(job);
}

let results = await Promise.all(jobs);

return results;
}
```

Comment: А какой результат даёт? Отправил обычный GET запрос из питона на `/users/${name}/repos` и получил верный json с информацией о репозиториях.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов Я проглядел! Там был массив PromiseResult. Спасибо.